# Opening new window on currently active monitor crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multiple-monitors

A user of my program reported that the buttons that open New Windows causes it to hang for 2 seconds then crash. Though it does not crash on any of the computers I have tested it on.

Even opening a window as simple as the copyright info text seems to make it crash.

[image: Axiom Crash]

---

Their PC specs:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Ryzen 5 1600 (6 core AMD CPU)
- Nvidia 1080 GPU
- 32GB RAM
- 3440x1440 monitor

---

This is how I open a window:

### Open New Window Button

This is pressed from the MainWindow.

```
private Boolean IsMyWindowOpened = false;
private void buttonMyWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Detect which screen we're on
    var allScreens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.ToList();
    var thisScreen = allScreens.SingleOrDefault(s => this.Left >= s.WorkingArea.Left && this.Left < s.WorkingArea.Right);
    if (thisScreen == null) thisScreen = allScreens.First();

    // Check if MyWindow is already open
    if (IsMyWindowOpened) return;

    // Start Window
    mywindow = new MyWindow();

    // Only allow 1 Window instance
    mywindow.ContentRendered += delegate { IsMyWindowOpened = true; };
    mywindow.Closed += delegate { IsMyWindowOpened = false; };

    // Position Relative to MainWindow
    // Keep from going off screen
    mywindow.Left = Math.Max(this.Left - mywindow.Width - 12, thisScreen.WorkingArea.Left);
    mywindow.Top = Math.Max(this.Top - 0, thisScreen.WorkingArea.Top);

    // Open Window
    mywindow.Show();
}
```

### New Window XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MyProgram.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded" 
        Height="200" 
        Width="450" 
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize" 
        UseLayoutRounding="True"
        Icon="Resources/Images/Icons/icon.ico"
</Window>
```

### New Window C Sharp

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    private MainWindow mainwindow;

    public MyWindow(MainWindow mainwindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.mainwindow = mainwindow;

        this.MinWidth = 450;
        this.MinHeight = 200;
        this.MaxWidth = 450;
        this.MaxHeight = 200;

        // Other Methods Here
    }

    // Other Methods Here
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Without exception logging (including, but not limited to, the one mentioned by Hans), you become entirely reliant on guesswork to find this, and any other problems your users have. Once you've added exception logging, make sure that your release build has the 'pdbonly' flag set, and that you ship the PDB files, so the exception gives you the most information possible.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable root causes for the crash are:

## System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.ToList() crashes

- Highly unlikely to happen

### Possible Fix

Replacing your filtering with

```
var thisScreen = Screen.FromControl(this);
```

### Possible Repro

See below

## SingleOrDefault crashes or returns null for some reason

- The first mention of a property of thisScreen causes a **NullReferenceException**, resulting in a crash.

### Possible fix

Replacing your filtering with

```
var thisScreen = Screen.FromControl(this);
```

#### IMPORTANT

- Look for other code that does similar things in your solution, and fix if any!
- Repro the issue to confirm the fix

### Possible Repro

- See  https://superuser.com/questions/1142074/windows-10-e-and-my-laptop-display-is-5-what-is-thi and https://communities.intel.com/thread/110642 for details

Possible long shot, but could be related!

I've encountered issues with a combination Hyper-V, Intel Display Drivers and multi-monitor setups, involving  fake monitors in Display Settings when Hyper-V was installed. In this state, connecting an extra monitor with any sort of cable would not work (no signal). It would only show the startup spinner on the extra monitor during windows restart and then boom no signal on all attempts).

It would look something like one of these pictures in Display Settings (even without any extra monitor connected):

[image: Display Settings would look something like this]

[image: Or this]

Find a computer with an Intel-based motherboard and Intel Display Drivers and try to get to the state described by installing Hyper-V. If by chance the current versions of Hyper-V or Intel Display Drivers no longer exhibit the weird behavior, try to find versions that do.

## Other issues:

- you say "ensure one instance of mywindow" but you actually leak instances! You never unsubscribe from the events, so about forms live on forever after shown. Ensuring only one instance of myWindow EVER exists is a good idea!
- you create the window instance before actually needing it (it should be after if)
- you can set the bool to true way before the "Render", right after the if, and eliminate one of the event subscription responsibility :)
- method "design" can be improved

These issues do not seem to have much potential to cause the crash you describe. Just to make sure, you should add some error logging/checking for better troubleshooting in the future!

Comment: I used some of your suggestions. I don't have a 3440x1440 monitor to test it on. The user will have to get back to me to see if the changes work.

Comment: Can you update the code in your answer? Maybe other things pop up when seeing the new one

Comment: I wish people would offer feedback rather than downvote

Comment: The crash has nothing to do with the resolution. If it were, worst case scenario: you go off-screen. Your code seemed logically sane to me, but risky. The real problem I think is with something more devious, some driver voodoo. Perhaps the filtering could have worked almost as it was originally with some extra checks. See my updated answer!

Comment: @MattMcManis i forgot to tag you, did you notice my latest update?

Answer (score 0):

Alex.C is right. I had similar issues with System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens. It just returned null sometimes. So replacing the code with var thisScreen = Screen.FromControl(this); should solve this problem

Comment: Really? It returned null? That's really really weird to me, I wasn't expecting that to be the root cause!

Comment: Did you find a repro?

Comment: Looking at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Screen.cs,118 it seems unlikely to me. I might be talking bs, but wouldn't there always be a PrimaryScreen in the list at least?